# CSS Responsive image technique mystery

Tags: css, image

I've been messing around with some responsive image techniques and came across one thing which confuses me.

I have an image wrapped in a `href` tag inside a container. The container serves as a well, container to hold everything together. The `href` tag serves as the image container with a specific size defined. The image `width` is then set to 100% to fit its container.

Here's the code:

```
The HTML:
---------
<div class="img-conatiner"> 
    <a href="#" class="img-grid">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="kittens!">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-grid">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="kittens!">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-grid">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="kittens!">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-grid">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="kittens!">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-grid">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="kittens!">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="img-grid">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="kittens!">
    </a>
</div>

The CSS
-------
body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: tomato;
}

.img-grid {
    width: 20%;
    float: left; <-- what is this for?
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-grid img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TBVWG/2/

Here's the thing, without the `float`, this technique doesn't work, the image blows up to its original size, ignoring the width of parent container. But how is the `float` keeping everything together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating an element automatically makes it a block element. 
[Here's an article talking about implied blocks](http://css-tricks.com/implied-block/).

If you don't have float `<a>` is displayed as a span which you can't set the width of, so the the `<a>` expands to fit the actual size of the image inside.

Comment: That link you gave explained everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably width:100% of .img-grid img causing this issue. Try to use absolute width/height of images. You can remove float then. A good article on float is available at - http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

You can't set width of an a-tag by default, you have to make it into a block element first.
Add `display:block;` to `.img-grid` and it will solve your problem.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TBVWG/2/)